# useRef to scroll horizontally don't work for a dynamic element

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, use-ref

I have a search field that adds tags to the left side, which after a certain number of tags added it shows overflow-x.
I need that after adding a new tag, it scrolls to the right, showing the last searched tag.

The code I made uses the useRef associated with the parent element, so that after inserting a new tag it calls a function that makes the scroll.

The problem is that for some reason, regardless of the value I put in pixels for the scroll, it always reaches the penultimate element, it never reaches the end.

I believe that when he activates the scroll the last element is not yet ready in the useRef, so the penultimate element would be the last one at the moment, but I still haven't found a way to get around this.

**My code:** https://codesandbox.io/s/nextjs-10-tailwind-2-0-forked-wergkg?file=/pages/index.js

some predefined tags have already been added so that the overflow is already visible
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be fixed like this:

1. Remove `scrollRight();` from your `handleKeyDown` handler.
2. Update `scrollRight` as below which will get the current width of scroll area instead fixed 600 pixels:

```
  const scrollRight = () => {
    scrollElement.current.scrollLeft += scrollElement.current.scrollWidth;
  };
```

3. Add the following `useEffect` to make the scroll once after the search item is added:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    scrollRight();
  }, [tagSearch]);
```

Working Demo:

[image: Edit NextJS 10 + Tailwind 2.0 (forked)]